# Canvas.js does not render chart dynamically

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, charts, canvasjs

I'm currently working on with data-visualising. What I'm trying to do, is to get some data from sql-database and visualize that. However, when im trying to render chart again, it gives an blank chart. I'm using dropdown-menu, where I have regions. Chart should render the selected option.

I'm using ajax to get that data.

Here is my code:
AJAX & js.

```
var datpoint = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#form-control").change(function () {
        var id = $('#form-control').val().toString();
        //alert(id);
        var serviceURL2 = '/Home/jsonSukupuol';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: serviceURL2,
            data: { a: id },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFuncSuk,
            error: errorFunc
        });

    function successFuncSuk(data, status) {
        datpoint = data;
        //alert(datpoint);
        chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = datpoint;
        chart.render();
        //window.onload();
    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
        }
    });
});

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "theme2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "example chart"
            },
            subtitles: [
                { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
            ],
            data: [
                {
                    type: "pie", 
                    dataPoints: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
                }
            ]
        });

window.onload = function () {
        chart.render();
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult jsonSukupuol(string a)
    {
        List<DataPoint> dataPoints = Kortit(a);
        var datPoin = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);
        return Json(datPoin, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I get the right data, i can see that when i'm using alerts. However, this chart just renders blank chart.

This is what i get when i'm rendering first time, using viewbag here.

[image: Data i get first time]

This is what i get when I'm rendering data again (ajax data).

[image: Data i get after rendering again]

**EDIT:**
I tried to get info using 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
in successFuncSuk.

results:  "[{\"label\":\"Mies\",\"y\":547892},{\"label\":\"Nainen\",\"y\":491164}]". Also there was some error: TypeError: l.dataPoints[t].x is undefined

Comment: please share a sample of the `data` passed to `successFuncSuk` --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: This is what i get to console: 
"[{\"label\":\"Mies\",\"y\":547892},{\"label\":\"Nainen\",\"y\":491164}]" 

Also there was some error:
TypeError: l.dataPoints[t].x is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Btw, thanks a lot, didn't remember to use that console.log! So I googled about that TypeError. The right solution is this:

```
function successFuncSuk(data, status) { 
    var finals = []; var tabData = JSON.parse(data); 
    for (var i = 0; i < tabData.length; i++) { 
        finals.push({ 'label': tabData[i].label, 'y': tabData[i].y}); 
    } 
    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = finals; chart.render(); 
}
```

Now it works. I just needed to parse that data again.